The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "NewPost"} was not handled by any navigator
I have stack navigation, and I would like to access the 'NewPost' component, but it shows the error above
app.routes.js
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Profile from '../pages/Profile';
import Search from '../pages/Search';
import NewPost from '../pages/NewPost';
import PostUser from '../pages/PostUser';
// import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

//NAVEGAÇÃO EM PILHA
function StackScreen(){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NewPost" component={NewPost} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PostUser" component={PostUser}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


index.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import  Feather  from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import  { Container, ButtonPost }  from './styles';

export default function Home() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
 return (
    <Container>

        <ButtonPost onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewPost') }>
          <Feather
          name="edit-2"
          color="#FFF"
          size={25}
          />
        </ButtonPost>

    </Container>
  );
}

I'm new to programming and I really don't know where I'm going wrong, thanks in advance for any help
(Ignore a alteração feita!)

(Ignore a alteração feita!)
